# Why does R fail to evaluate this line?

Tags: r

R fails to evaluate at line 15. Could someone tell me why it fails?
This is a simple program that makes all products of numbers of length 3. Then finds the largest of these that is a palindrome number, e.g., 9009.

```
largestpalndrome3 <- function(){
products3 <- c()
i <- 100
while(i <= 999){
    j <- i
    while(j <= 999){
        products3[i] <- i*j
        j <- j+1
    }
    i <- i+1
}
palindromes <- c()
i <- 1
for(prod in products3){
    if(prod<100000){
        prodcopy <- prod
        o <- prodcopy %% 10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        t <- prodcopy %% 10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        h <- prodcopy %% 10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        th <- prodcopy %% 10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        tth <- prodcopy %% 10
        hth <- prodcopy%/%10
        if(o==hth & t==tth & h==th){
            palindromes[i] <- prod
        }
    }
    if(prod>100000){
        prodcopy <- prod
        o <- prodcopy %% 10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        t <- prodcopy %% 10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        h <- prodcopy %% 10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        tth <- prodcopy %% 10
        prodcopy = prodcopy%/%10
        hth <- prodcopy%%10
        m <- prodcopy%/%10
        if(o==m & t==hth & h==tth){
            palindromes[i] <- prod
        }
    }
    i <- i + 1
}
}
```

Comment: There really isn't any reason to have this as a function yet.  It's easier to debug if it isn't a function.  The way you set up products3 isn't doing what you're hoping it's doing.

Comment: ok I fixed the nested loop, but the eval at line 15 still fails

Comment: It is not completely fixed: look at `head(products3)`.

Comment: Your `products3[i] <-` has a whole bunch of `NA` at the beginning because your `i` only starts at 100 (so the first 99 values are NA). You could do `products3 <- products[100:length(products3)]` after your loop, or do `products3[i-99] <- i*j`.

Comment: Since `i<-100`, `product3[1]` is `NA` which can't be compared with 100000. 'o' is a terrible variable name. You should increment

Comment: Sorry messed up my last comment. You should increment `i` only if a palindrome is found. There is no `hth` digit when `prod < 100000`. There is no `m` digit when `prod > 100000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would solve your problem:

```
palindromes = function(n=3){

A1 = c((10^n-1):10^(n-1))
A2 = as.character(A1)


ltrs= sapply(A2,substring,1:n,1:n)
rownames(ltrs)=c(1:n)
ltrs=  ltrs[order(rownames(ltrs),decreasing=T),]
ltrs= apply(ltrs,2,paste,collapse='')


A2 = as.numeric(paste(A2,ltrs,sep=''))

A3= combn((10^n-1):10^(n-1),2)
A4 = A3[1,]*A3[2,]

largestpal = max(A2[ A2 %in% A4])

prod2= A3[,which(A4==largestpal)]

return(list('Number of Digits'=n, 'Largest Palindrome'=largestpal,'multiple of'=prod2))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the error is that in the way you have defined **product3**, the first 99 elements of it are `NA`.

Before using a value, you have to perform a check. One simple step is to use the `is.na()` check.

Here's a small change that first checks **whether prod is NA** and proceeds if it isn't.  This will get you past your error.

```
for(prod in products3){

        if(!is.na(prod)) {
            ...
            your code here
            ...
        }
    }
```

@AndresT gives you a different (and more efficient) way to do what you are attempting.